# Clustering with KPrototypes

Tags: python, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

Hello I'm having some trouble when trying to cluster with KPrototypes. My data set has the following structure;

```
0  1    2    3    4    5 
1  0.3  1.2  2.2  4.4  4.4
2  1.2  1.4  1.5  2.5  4.1
3  1    0    1    0    1
4  0    1    0    1    0
```

And my code is as following;

```
from kmodes.kprototypes import KPrototypes
test=KPrototypes(n_clusters=2, init='Huang')
cluster=test.fit_predict(X, categorical=[3,4])
```

My problem is that i can't seem to define the categorical dummy variables in the code. Categorical=[3,4] refers to the third amd fourth column and not row.

Anyone got a suggestion how to define the rows and not columns?

Comment: Generally an entire column is categorical or numerical.

Answer (score 2):

KPrototypes expects columns as the variables. You can transpose X but note that the column indexing starts from zero, so for the example above, you'd have:

```
cluster=test.fit_predict(X.T, categorical=[2,3])
```